# Script run only on specific sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

can you please tell me, how to change code to run script only on specified sheet? I want to send e-mails if some value in 2nd column of specified sheet will change. Currently it is sending e-mails if I change 2nd column in any sheet.

I have tried code below, but didn't work:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('sheetname'))
```

This is code I have:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = mycell.getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "email@email.com";
  if (cellcol == 2)
  {
   var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
   var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps ini your script, you just call active sheet, you don't check which one is the active sheet

Comment: You can check with if (sheet.getName()==`your sheet name') BLA BLA ....

Comment: Bound scripts are parts of projects and all scripts in a project have access to all sheets in the Spreadsheet that it's bound to.  If you want to run a function on a specific sheet then use `var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SheetName');`  and limit you actions to `sheet`.